# Python scripts not running on Sublime text

Tags: python, ubuntu-one, python3, sublime-text

I'm using Sublime text text editor on Ubuntu 20.04 downloaded from Ubuntu software. When I try running a Python script it gives me "bash : python : command not found" then gives me the path to 'snap' where the sublime text was downloaded to.
How do I fix this so that Python scripts run on the Sublime text text editor?

Comment: I think it should be 'python' with lowercase letter 'p'!

Answer (score 0):

I think you used 'P' rather than 'p' for the python command. Update your command and it should run.

Make that `python ...` rather than `Python ...`.

Comment: I've corrected the typo. Might you have any solution to the problem?

Comment: If this solve the first problem kindly acknowledge that by clicking on the check beside the answer, then ask another question! @tsargatxy

Comment: my problem isn't fixed. A simple "print('Hello World')" is not running on my Sublime text editor.  You've only criticized my earlier typo, I fail to see your solution to the question asked sir.